# Calculator in C programming

Tags: c

This is the code for simple calculator in C and I implement on Visual Studio Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char opr;
    double fnum,snum;
    printf("Choose operation [A(+),B(-),C(*),D(/)]: ");
    scanf("%c",&opr);

    printf("Two numbers: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&fnum,&snum);

    switch (opr)
    {
    case 'A':
        printf("%lf + %lf = %lf",fnum,snum,fnum+snum);
        break;

    case 'B':
        printf("%lf - %lf = %lf",fnum,snum,fnum-snum);
        break;

    case 'C':
        printf("%lf * %lf = %lf",fnum,snum,fnum*snum);
        break; 
        
    case 'D':
        printf("%lf / %lf = %lf",fnum,snum,fnum/snum);
        break;
    
    default:
        printf("Invalid Operator");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When I run it, I got these output. I choose the operation as A and two numbers as 20 and 10, but it gives 0.+0.=0. as an output instead of giving 20.+10.=30. I cannot find why, thanks.

```
Choose operation [A(+),B(-),C(*),D(/)]: A
Two numbers: 20 10
0.000000 + 0.000000 = 0.000000
```

Comment: Remark: there is no need to use those letters, just input the special characters to specify the operation.

Comment: It is for the assignment, you can simply disregard it, the main question is what I explain.

Comment: You need to use %lf in scanf to read in doubles.

Comment: You describe what you see when you run it, but what do you see when you debug it? (Add variables to watch-window, and so on)

Comment: You are using the wrong conversion specifier for scanf. `double` should be `%lf` not `%f`. You should also enable warnings for your compiler, it would have catched this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format string to `scanf` is incorrect.  You use `%f` to read a float but you need `%lf` to read a double.